# What are some good approaches for reusing parts of a config?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have several grids that share common columns for example (the issue is not limited to columns, any config object). Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
//columns.js
var columns = {"reusable1": {...}, "reusable2": {...}};

//grid views
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Grid', {
    columns: [
        {text:'inline column1'},
        columns.reusable1,
        columns.reusable2,
        {text:'inline column2'},
    ]
});
```

This gets the job done, but what would be the better approach that works in a similar way (without creating unique `xtype` for each config piece, or modifying configs in a `constructor` or `initComponent`). I just want to be able to put misc reusable config pieces inline as before.

Answer (score 1):

I think most other options will likely reduce readability or just look outright convoluted - but you could override the base class and include a configuration for *"named"* columns instead.

I'm assuming when you say, *"not modifying configs in a constructor"* you are referring to the grid/s implementing the columns rather than similar logic that could be tidied away somewhere else.

```js
Ext.define('App.override.grid.column.Column', {
    override: 'Ext.grid.column.Column',

    config: {
        name: null    
    },

    statics: {
        namedColumns: {
            reusable1: { /* ... */ },
            reusable2: { /* ... */ },
            // ...
        }
    },

    constructor: function(args){
        var _args = args || {},
            statics = Ext.grid.column.Column,
            defaults = statics.namedColumns[_args.name] || {};
        this.callParent([Ext.apply({}, _args, defaults)]);
    }
});
```

**Usage**

```js
Ext.define('App.view.Grid', {
    columns: [
        { text: 'inline column1' },
        { name: 'reusable1'      },
        { name: 'reusable2'      },
        { text: 'inline column2' },
    ]
});
```

**Advantages**

- Tidied away within the project structure rather than existing in the global scope.
- Avoids potential dependency issues as Sencha CMD will ensure the override (and by extension these defaults) exist before any grid is declared.
- The named configurations are more flexible and may be neatly overridden inline.
  ***e.g.*** `{ name: 'reusable', flex: 2 /* superseding value */ }`

**Disadvantages**

- The `xtype` can't be used as part of the default configuration, this would still need to be specified inline for anything other than a regular grid-column. 
  ***e.g.*** `{ xtype: 'datecolumn', name: 'some-defaults' }`

[**» Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1frp)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these configs:

- [Ext.grid.Panel#cfg-defaults](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#cfg-defaults)
- [Ext.grid.Panel#cfg-columns](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#cfg-columns)

The `defaults` config works for the entire container, where as `columns` has its own defaults option.

Hope this helps!